# How to increase label box text Size in c# windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I using following code, When I run below code, Half of the text only displayed in label box. I want display full line in label box text? How to do it?

```
Label dynamiclabel1 = new Label();
dynamiclabel1.Location = new Point(280, 90);
dynamiclabel1.Name = "lblid";
dynamiclabel1.Size = new Size(150, 14);    
dynamiclabel1.Text="Smith had omitted the paragraph in question (an omission which had escaped notice for twenty years) on the ground that it was unnecessary and misplaced; but Magee suspected him of having been influenced by deeper reasons.";        
dynamiclabel1.AutoSize = true;
dynamiclabel1.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
panel1.Controls.Add(dynamiclabel1);
```

Comment: You have to use ".Width"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
            Label dynamiclabel = new Label();
            dynamiclabel.Location = new Point(38, 30);
            dynamiclabel.Name = "lbl_ques";
            dynamiclabel.Text = question;
            //dynamiclabel.AutoSize = true;
            dynamiclabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(900, 26);
            dynamiclabel.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have used `AutoSize` and explicit label size setting at the same time, this makes no sense.

If you want to enable word wrapping in your label text - you have to set `dynamiclabel1.AutoSize = false;` first and then increase its `Height`. Currently it has only 14 pixels of height so it is impossible to make text multiline. Increase it to something about 200 pixels and all the text will be placed inside the label in a few lines.

Comment: When increase the height 14 to 200 , the text displayed 10 lines. How to display within 2 or 3 lines?? @Andy Korneyev

Comment: @Param Answer is obvious - since text amount is constant you have to increase `Width` of label and decrease its `Height` to get fewer lines of text. For this particular text and font used it is something around `Size(500, 50)` in order to get whole text in three lines.

Comment: Its working. I have one doubt could you clarify? any properties is there to adjust label text size except Size(width,Height) properties?

Comment: I need automatically convert to next line depending upon text size.

Comment: @Param You have no other option except `Size` and `AutoSize`.`Autosize=true` will try to enlarge label width to fit whole text, but will keep it in one line only. Also you can use `TextRenderer.MeasureText` method to measute your expected text width and height in pexels when it will be displayed in label. Using this method and obtaining height from text and desired width and also assuming that each line of text in label has some constant height you can tweak whole label width/height according to your needs

Comment: @Param see if my answer fits your requirements

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the height, and want less rows, set the Width property to something bigger;

```
dynamiclabel1.Width = 150;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the number of lines depending on font/text size, you can do something like this:

```
Label dynamiclabel1 = new Label();
dynamiclabel1.Location = new Point(280, 90);
dynamiclabel1.Name = "lblid";
dynamiclabel1.Size = new Size(150, 100);
dynamiclabel1.Text = "Smith had omitted the paragraph in question (an omission which had escaped notice for twenty years) on the ground that it was unnecessary and misplaced; but Magee suspected him of having been influenced by deeper reasons.";

dynamiclabel1.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
int lines = 3; //number of lines you want your text to display in
using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
{
     SizeF size = g.MeasureString(dynamiclabel1.Text, dynamiclabel1.Font);
     float w=size.Width / lines;
     dynamiclabel1.Height = (int)Math.Ceiling(size.Height*lines);
     dynamiclabel1.Width = (int)Math.Ceiling(w);
}
panel1.Controls.Add(dynamiclabel1);
```

**Edit**
If what you know is the width you have available and you want your label to adjust height to show all the content, can do this:

```
Label dynamiclabel1 = new Label();
dynamiclabel1.Location = new Point(280, 90);
dynamiclabel1.Name = "lblid";
dynamiclabel1.Size = new Size(150, 100);
dynamiclabel1.Text = "Smith had omitted the paragraph in question (an omission which had escaped notice for twenty years) on the ground that it was unnecessary and misplaced; but Magee suspected him of having been influenced by deeper reasons.";

dynamiclabel1.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
int width  = 600; //Width available to your label
using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
{
    SizeF size = g.MeasureString(dynamiclabel1.Text, dynamiclabel1.Font);
    lines = (int)Math.Ceiling(size.Width / width);
    dynamiclabel1.Height = (int)Math.Ceiling(size.Height * lines);
    dynamiclabel1.Width = width;
}
panel1.Controls.Add(dynamiclabel1);
```

Comment: my real requirement is, I am developing Aptitude test by dotnet software. I have 15 question from DBI. Each question fill to dynamic label box text,  and there 4 radio button display answeres. Radio button are next to Label. Two question have long text. That time first three radio button are hided because question length.  I try to move the radio button there are more gap between question and answer. two question only lang. Could you understand my Requirement??

Comment: Hmm no,not really. Did you tried the code I provided? I asume this is Winforms isn't it?

Comment: See if my edit is what you want. If it's not, try to edit your question and add more info, a screen capture for example could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way to change size of controls like label/button in win forms:**

Right click on
`label/button control --> properties --> autosize =false.`

Now size can be changed.